# Setup trigger in Power Automate custom connector for Docusign

Tags: docusignapi, docusignconnect, power-automate-custom-connector

I'm creating a new trigger in Power Automate custom connector to receive DocuSign event, does anyone know what URL, header and body I should use?  Thank you.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The url for DocuSign trigger is [https://demo.docusign.net/restapi/v2.1/accounts/{accountId}/connect](https://demo.docusign.net/restapi/v2.1/accounts/%7BaccountId%7D/connect) （Test system). and body is

```
{
    "connectId": "",
    "configurationType": "custom",
    "urlToPublishTo": "https://docusigntest.mysite.com",
    "name": "test1234",
    "allowEnvelopePublish": "true",
    "deliveryMode": "",
    "enableLog": "false",
    "includeDocuments": "false",
    "includeCertificateOfCompletion": "false",
    "requiresAcknowledgement": "true",
    "signMessageWithX509Certificate": "false",
    "useSoapInterface": "false",
    "includeTimeZoneInformation": "true",
    "includeHMAC": "false",
    "includeEnvelopeVoidReason": "true",
    "includeSenderAccountasCustomField": "true",
    "envelopeEvents": [
        "Completed"
    ],
    "soapNamespace": "",
    "allUsers": "true",
    "includeCertSoapHeader": "false",
    "requireMutualTls": "false",
    "includeDocumentFields": "true",
    "eventData": {
        "version": "restv2.1",
        "includeData": ["documents","recipients"]
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

From:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/connectors/custom-connectors/create-webhook-trigger

> The webhook is created on the GitHub side by an HTTP POST to
> /repos/{owner}/{repo}/hooks. When a new logic app or flow is created,
> it posts to this URL using the trigger defined in the OpenAPI
> definition. It also posts to the URL if the trigger is modified. In
> the sample below, the post property contains the schema of the request
> that is posted to GitHub.

I suspect you didn't realize this is an advanced option, that require that you also have a web app on the other side. If you are a developer and have a web app - then you will know the URL for your app.

If you are looking for no-code/low-code option to get triggers from DocuSign, your best option is to use the connector that already exists in there - https://flow.microsoft.com/en-us/connectors/shared_docusign/docusign/

Comment: Thanks for reply, I'm aware of how webhook works. The question is like you said, the URL for GitHub is /repos/{owner}/{repo}/hooks,  but what it is for DocuSign?

Comment: no, it's for your own repo